# Set.retainAll () on API 45 dies with UnexpectedException

Tags: apex, failing-tests

I have a weird issue, can somebody help?

On API 45, the following test crashes with

```
FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to apex.bytecodeinterpreter.ObjectInstance
```

on set2.retainAll (set1).

If I save the same class as API 44, all is well, and Set.retainAll () works as expected.

```
@isTest
public class UnexpectedTest {

    @isTest
    public static void testSet () {
        Set<Id> set1 = new Set<id> {'0MI4E0000000NrOWAU', '0MI4E0000000NrNWAU'};
        Set<Id> set2 = new Set<id> {'0MI4E0000000NrNWAU', '0MI4E0000000NrOWAU'};

        set2.retainAll (set1);
        System.debug (set2);
    }
}
```

This happens on all orgs I have access to.

**Update 2019-04-01**: I have just tried it again, and it seems to work now with API 45

Comment: If you have confirmed this is API 45.0 issue, then you would need to contact Support to verify if this is an issue with the Spring release.

Comment: @ca_peterson You might be interested in taking a look at this.

Comment: Bug filed as W-5851163. Thanks for the great repro case.

Comment: Also heads up that sfse mentions don't alert me - generally better to tweet at me if you want to flag me down for comments on a specific question.

Comment: You're welcome. I had hoped I might have done something I could correct. But well, workaround exists for now.

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly related to the known issue [The result of Set.retainAll(Set) are inconsistent between ApexCode log level is FINEST and it is FINER(or lower)](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HlAfQAK) being resolved in Spring '19.

It's specifically tied to the current logging level.

In my Dev Org, which is currently on Spring '19 Patch 8.7 your sample test class fails with the message:

> System.UnexpectedException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to apex.bytecodeinterpreter.ObjectInstance

But, only if the ApexCode logging level is set to **FINEST**. If I dial it back to **FINER** the test passes just fine.

Or it might be [The result of List.contains() are inconsistent between ApexCode log level is FINEST and it is FINER(or lower)](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000AT9cQAG). I don't have any inside information on this, but I think it is safe to say they are probably related.

---

Update from [twitter](https://twitter.com/ca_peterson/status/1095490718968143872), sounds like they are onto it now.

> Bug filed as W-5851163